# tsc: not found error in heroku despite trying everything

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, tsc

I am trying to deploy a simple nodejs app to heroku but getting the above error. Tried solving it based on the available answers here, but nothing seems to work. Here's what I have tried already:

1. Installed typescript buildpack on dyno `heroku buildpacks: heroku/nodejs zidizei/typescript`
2. My package.json has typescript in devDependencies, and scripts has tsc in the build argument

```
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.0"
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/server.js",
    "postinstall": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    "start:server": "ts-node server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
...
```

3. My tsconfig.json also matches pretty much with the answer that I've seen here

```
{
   "ts-node": {
   "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "commonjs"
   }
 },
 "compilerOptions": {
   "module": "commonjs",
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "target": "es6",
   "rootDir": "./",
   "outDir": "./build",
   "strict": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
   "moduleResolution":"node",
   "skipLibCheck": true
 },
 "files": [ "./utils/index.d.ts" ]
}
```

Error I am getting on the build step:

```
-----> TypeScript app detected
-----> Creating build environment
-----> Installing development dependencies
       Installing development node modules (npm)
       npm WARN invalid config only="dev" set in command line options
       npm WARN invalid config Must be one of: null, prod, production
       
       > rmr@1.0.0 postinstall
       > npm run build
       
       
       > rmr@1.0.0 build
       > tsc
       
       sh: 1: tsc: not found
       npm notice
       npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.1.0 -> 10.2.3
       npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.3>
       npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.3` to update!
       npm notice
       npm ERR! code 127
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_5663ceba
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh -c npm run build
```

Exhausted all ideas about what I might be doing wrong and looking to get enlightened on the same. Any other things I should try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you installing your dependencies? npm i or npm ci? Cause typescript is a devDependency

Comment: I think heroku installs it as npm i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by putting tsc into build instead of postinstall, as heroku calls npm start build. At postinstall stage, it seems, devDependencies are no longer accessible.

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/server.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    "start:server": "ts-node server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```